# Jquery Datetimepicker adds more watchers since it uses $watch()

Tags: jquery, angularjs, performance, web, datetimepicker

I have been trying to improve the performance of my angularjs application, and one of the best practices says we need to reduce the number of watchers, and one thing noticed is if I have a Jquery DateTimePicker in my view the number of watchers increase considerably, is there a way to reduce this when using the DateTimePicker?

Comment: It would be great to look at the code you want to improve, because in some cases it may not be possible. At least one possible thing is to use one-way binding instead of two-ways when possible

Comment: Take a look at ui-bootstrap datepicker https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker and try to use ng-bind directive wherever possible also take a look at "::" operator bind once
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: Actually it's not in my code, I'm using a plugin for Jquery Datetimepicker and inside that they are actually using $watch @JavaEvgen

Comment: I've used one way binding wherever  I could, the thing is can't use ui-bootstrap datepicker @PanosK